# I am actively interviewing and my current company may know it. Should I just quit before fired?

Tags: job-change, quitting

I am actively looking for job and interviewing and used PTO frequently. And it looks like my manager already know about that based on his behavior, such as he gave some task was planned to give me to other people.

I have not gotten an offer yet, but I have lots in-coming onsite. Our company has precedent that one person has been fired because he told other co-worker he was looking for jobs. I have not told anyone, but I feel my manger knows.

Should I just quit the job? I do not really want to be fired and has bad record.

Comment: Duplicate of many other questions that have been closed. We can't give you advice on whether or not to quit.

Comment: "one person has been fired because he told other co-worker" - so don't tell other coworkers. Keep your interviewing to yourself until you're ready to make definite plans.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I just quit the job? I do not really want to be fired and has
>   bad record.

No, don't quit.

First, you don't really know what your manager knows and doesn't know. You have a suspicion, but you don't really know. And as @teego1967 points out, even if your boss knows, that doesn't mean you will be fired.

Second, you are much better served finding your next job while you are still on a payroll. Being without income while looking for a job can hurt in several ways. Some employers downgrade candidates who are unemployed (I'm not saying this is a good thing, but it does happen). Additionally, financial pressures can force people to accept jobs that they aren't happy with and will shortly leave.

Instead, ramp up your efforts to find your next job. Land one then hand in yor notice.

Comment: I would add that it's not a given that the OP's boss will necessarily fire him if he finds out he is looking. Prepare for it by reassigning projects? Sure. But everyone looks for new jobs sometimes, even bosses, and the vast majority of the time people don't get fired if.word gets out by accident.

Comment: Looking for a job while not currently employed certainly puts you in a weaker position when it comes to salary negotiations.

Answer (score 2):

So, at least one other person was fired because the company knew he was looking.  You haven't been fired yet, so that means:
(a) The company doesn't know yet that you are actively looking; or
(b) the company does know, but has decided not to fire you (yet).

Either way, I cannot see any benefit from quitting.  You want to be sufficiently far along in the job-hunting process that, even if the company does fire you, it won't matter any more.  The longer you stay, the more likely that is.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of all the advantages to you if you quit because you suspect that you might get fired. I think that list will be very, very empty. Then make a list of all the advantages to you if you don't quit. Now there are the two possibilities: The company wants to fire you, or they don't.

If they don't want to fire you, which is reasonably likely (since I hear they fired someone, and at some point they will run out of people to do the work), then you seriously lose if you quit: No income, no job (much easier to get a job if you have one, and if you tell the new employer you left because you thought you are going to get fired that is seriously off-putting). Even if they want to fire you, it is almost always better to be let go than to leave with no new job available.